# Convert bson to json in python/pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I'm trying to convert bson data gotten straight from pymongo into json data. Is there a straight forward way to do this with python using pymongo or something else?

Here's the code if it helps:

```
def email_main(request):
    collection = get_collection("nimbus").fullcontact_email_data
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = collection.save(dict(request.POST.iterlists()))
        response = HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
    elif request.method == "GET":
        getParams = convertQuerydictToDict(request.GET)
        page, itemsPerPage = getPageDataFromDict(getParams)
        getParamsWithNoPageData = createDictWithoutPageData(getParams)
        data = collection.find(getParamsWithNoPageData)[page:page+itemsPerPage+1]
        response = HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(status=404)
    return response


def convertQuerydictToDict(queryDict):
    return dict(queryDict.iterlists())


def getPageDataFromDict(myDict):
    if "page" in myDict and "itemsPerPage" in myDict:
        page, itemsPerPage = myDict["page"], myDict['itemsPerPage']
    elif "page" in myDict:
        page, itemsPerPage = myDict["page"], 10
    else:
        page, itemsPerPage = 0, 10
    return page, itemsPerPage

def createDictWithoutPageData(myDict):
    newDict = deepcopy(myDict)
    newDict.pop("page", None)
    newDict.pop("itemsPerPage", None)
    return newDict
```

basically that data variable needs to get turned into proper json. There must be some built in thing that does this.

For clarity here's what I get when I put data into the python console:

```
>>> data
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x4dd0f50>
>>> data[0]
{u'blah': u'go', u'_id': ObjectId('540e3fd8bb6933764d5650b7')}
```

ObjectId is not part of the json spec...

Comment: How does this code's behavior differ from what you intend? What exactly is the type of the `data` variable which you want to transform into JSON? Are we to assume that `collection.save` refers to [this PyMongo API call](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.save), or something else?

Comment: data is returned as pymongo cursor object. When you iterate through this object the data returned is in bson format which includes things that are not compatible with JSON. I just want that data variable to return json rather then bson, or convert it if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`json_util` module in PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html), which seems to address this issue? "provide explicit BSON conversion to and from json"

Comment: Also, `data` is not in BSON format. The BSON is parsed into a python data structure.

Comment: @wdberkeley, right. It's not obvious from this code example **what** the type of `data` is. Without knowing that, one can only speculate on how to convert it to JSON.

Comment: I updated the question with an example for clarity. I just looked at json_util again. From looking at the example they gave it looked like I needed to put in a dictionary literal with functions like Code() to specify what's a string. But I tried it in the console and it works for serializing all types of BSON data into a string. Dan if you answer the question I'll mark yours as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, it appears that the best approach is to use PyMongo's [`json_util` module](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html) to handle the gory details of converting BSON to JSON.